# removing patch 1533 from Magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7, patches, supee-8788v2

I want to apply patch 8788 in my magento 1.7.0.2 but can't get it installed as it is throwing few errors such as: Hunk #1 FAILED at 154. etc..

I googled it and found that patch 1533 might be the reason of this issue.

I checked applied.patches.list file and found the patch 1533 installed:

```
015-04-19 17:26:58 UTC | SUPEE-1533 | EE_1.12 | v1 | _ | n/a | SUPEE-1533_EE_1.12_v1.patch
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
```

I think i have to remove this patch 1533 in order to install patch 8788. But I can't find any .sh file related to the patch 1533 in the root of magento. That means i can't technically remove patch 1533 from magento if i dont know where this file is located.

Can any one help me to remove patch 1533 however i don't have any idea where the .sh file is located.

Comment: issue is resolved?

Comment: @RamaChandran not yet

Comment: i will help you. how to resolve issue :)

Comment: @RamaChandran I will really appreciate if you can help me. What other information you need from me